# Datatable.Compute() returns value only when it is positive value

Tags: c#

I have a column(Profit Decimal(8,2) Not Null) in a table, my db is .sdf type.(Sql Server Compact). I want to sum the values of the Profit column. Sum the positive values in sumProfit and sum the negative values to sumLoss as shown in the code below

```
private DataTable dtbDailyOrders = MobileLine.getDailyOrdersByDate(from, to, out error);
if (dtbDailyOrders != null)
{
    if (dtbDailyOrders.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        bindToGrid(dtbDailyOrders);
        object sumProfit;
        sumProfit = dtbDailyOrders.Compute("Sum(Profit)", "Profit>=0");
        object sumLoss;
        sumLoss =   dtbDailyOrders.Compute("Sum(Profit)", "Profit<0");
        if(sumProfit == null)
        {
            // I check if it is null, but It is not null
        }
        txtProfit.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(sumProfit.ToString()).ToString("N2");
        txtLoss.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(sumLoss.ToString()).ToString("N2");
    }
}
```

For testing I have inserted one row in my table. if value of Profit=5 the sumProfit returns 5, but if the value is -5 it returns something like this

```
sumProfit | {}
```

I try to check if it is null but it is not null

```
if(sumProfit == null)
{
    string isNull = "the value is null";
}
```

When I convert the sumProfit or the sumLoss I get exception error

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

can anyone please explain why it is like this.?

Comment: I don't understand, why should sumProfit with Profit = -5 return anything? You have filter >= 0 on sumProfit.

Comment: exactly, why should it return  this sumProfit | {}. I thought it should return null, but it is not null either.

Comment: You ought to check the type of the column in DataTable.  Smells like it got mapped to a string instead of decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Compute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute) will never return null. If the expression evaluates to null, the return value will be [DBNull.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value)

So your check should be `if(DBNull.Value.Equals(sumProfit))`

This also explains the conversion expression, because the `DBnull.Value.ToString()` method will not return a convertible string.

Answer (score 0):

To check null value you can use **DBNull.Value.Equals(sum)** or **string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sum.ToString())**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(System.Int32)));
            DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
            dr2["Profit"] = DBNull.Value;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr2);
            var sum=dt.Compute("Sum(Profit)", "Profit>=0");
            if (DBNull.Value.Equals(sum))
                Console.WriteLine("the value is null");
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sum.ToString()))
                Console.WriteLine("the sum is null");
```